# How can i use jquery-like selector on django templates (html) to retrieve a piece of that template?

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, css-selectors

I want to fetch a piece of my django templates with a jquery-like selection.

An example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<h2>Category: {{ name }}</h2>

<p class="desc">{{ phase.name }}. Since : {{ due_date|date:"d/m/Y H:i:s" }}</p>

<div id="list">
    <ul>
        {% for o news.all %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ o.url }}">{{ o.title }}</a> - Value: {{ o.value }}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

If i do

```
piece = pyq("#list ul")
```

piece will be

```
<ul>
    {% for o news.all %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ o.url }}">{{ o.title }}</a> - Value: {{ o.value }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Are there packages / apps that allow me to do this?

If not, what is the fastest solution to achieve that? Is it possible or it's too hard?

I want to get that because in ajax i don't want to create a lot of fragments (with includes).

PS: **i'm pretty used to jQuery and Django Templates (tags and filters like include)**. Of course with django i can't do this, that's why i'm asking for package / apps if exists. Maybe the question is not clear, my English is poor :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want access to the template before it is rendered you can create a template with just the code you want.

```
#your_news_list_template.html
<ul>
  {% for o news.all %}
<li>
  <a href="{{ o.url }}">{{ o.title }}</a> - Value: {{ o.value }}
</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

you can then include that in any other template or just render it to a string.

`{% include "path/to/your_news_list_template.html" %}`

if you do this make sure you include `news` in your context

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include  documents this.  This will let you reuse this block in any template.

If you need the html AFTER django renders it you can use one of the libraries listed below:

You can parse HTML using jquery selectors with the Spynner library.  It might have more overhead than what you had in mind though. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/spynner

I just found out about pyquery which lets you use jquery -like syntax to select elements. http://packages.python.org/pyquery/

Comment: ye but pyquery don't do this on django templates, only on pure html.

that's the point: i don't want to do an include for each fragment i need to reload via AJAX.

anyway i didn't know spynner, useful link thanx

Comment: @avastreg why wouldn't includes work for ajax? usually the template fragments would work perfect for ajax.  If you have an ajax call that loads more news items it makes sense to have a news_items template.

Comment: my wish is to avoid many and many includes, simply pointing a div in ajax request, without need to extract the piece, create a template and include it in the page.

in that way, i can create ajax calls avoiding to touch the template, or create others to include.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use jQuery to select a part of the HTML of a webpage. It can't be used to select a part of a Django template because a Django template is used to *generate* the HTML itself. That means the Django syntax is already 'gone' by the time jQuery runs. In your case, the jQuery selector can select the `ul` as it is in the HTML but it won't contain any Django specific code or template syntax.

Comment: jquery-like, not jQuery of course.

i want something like pyquery http://packages.python.org/pyquery/index.html# but on django templates